# Max Fourier Transform in a given time interval python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, dft

The following is a code for a Discrete Fourier Transform using python:

```
def dft(y):
    N = len(y)
    c = np.zeros(N//2+1,complex)
    for k in range(N//2+1):
        for n in range(N):
            c[k] += y[k]*np.exp(-2j*np.pi*k*n/N)
    return c
```

How is it possible to determine the largest vector you can transform in a given time interval? (for example, the largest vector you can transform in 1 sec)

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do it is empirically finding the relationship of `N` vs time, with the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module. With enough points you could calculate it's fitting equation. And then you could approximate the value of `N` that will be processed in a given time.

But depending on your application, you should be aware that you might be interested on the worst case scenario.